# Invoking initializer for AVAudioRecorder - Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, swift2, initializer

This seems to be an issue that I am having with the transition to Swift 2.0:

I am trying to initialize my AVAudioRecorder and the settings parameter (which I used to give nil) will not accept this anymore. Thoughts?

```
*var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch{
        }
        audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil)
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()*
```

It gives me the error: **

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVAudioRecorder' with an argument
>   list type '(URL: NSURL, settings:nil)'."

**

filePath is of type NSURL by the way. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a problem like this, *look at the declaration in the header*:

```
init(URL url: NSURL, settings: [String : AnyObject]) throws
```

As you can see clearly from that declaration, just about everything about this line is wrong:

```
audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil)
```

- You cannot supply `nil` settings. Pass an empty dictionary if you have no settings.
- This is a `throws` initializer; you must say `try` and enclose it in a `do/catch` structure.

Comment: That solves it. It was the empty dictionary that I was looking for. Also, thank you for the heads up on the throw initializer. This would have been an issue next. Fixed both! Thanks again!

Comment: To be quite honest, I wonder whether this is a bug. Surely passing `nil` here _should_ be legal — it always has been. I'm going to report it.

Comment: Apple told me this isn't a bug. You should never have been passing `nil`. Settings are needed.